# Jade versus Pug

Tags: pug

I have an example that uses the engine jade, but jade is now pug.
If I use jade-code 1:1:

```
 br
 hr
 if post.comments
  h3 Comments
  each comment, i in post.comments
   .comment
    p.comment-name #{comment.name}
    p.comment-body #{comment.body}
  br
```

the following error occurs:

```
  TypeError: C:\LearnNodejs\nodeblog\views\show.pug:20
  18|       each comment, i in post.comments
  19|        .comment
> 20|         p.comment-name #{comment.name}
  21|         p.comment-body #{comment.body}
  22|       br
  23|     h3 Add Comment
 Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Adapted to pug (a try):

```
br
 hr
 if post.comments.name !== undefined
  h3 Comments
  each comment, i in post.comments
   .comment
    p.comment-name comment.name
    p.comment-body comment.body
br
```

shows the following:

```
Comments
comment.name
comment.body
comment.name
comment.body
comment.name
comment.body
comment.name
comment.body
comment.name
comment.body
```

the javascript:

```
router.get('/show/:id', function(req, res, next) {  
Post.findById(req.params.id,function(err, post){
res.render('show',{
    'post': post
    });
  });
});
```

What should the pug-code look like for the display?
Thanks for a support.

Answer (score 2):

The [interpolation syntax](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html) for Pug is mostly the same as it was for Jade. You still need to wrap your variables in `#{}` in order to output them as text.

Try this:

```
if post.comments.name !== undefined
  h3 Comments
  each comment, i in post.comments
    .comment
      p.comment-name #{comment.name}
      p.comment-body #{comment.body}
```

If that doesn't work, your `post.comments` object may be structured differently than you expect. If `post.comments` is an array and you want to check if the first item has a name, that `if` statement may need to change to:

```
if post.comments[0].name !== undefined
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It works with:   each comment in [post.comments]   // p=comment.name // p=comment.boy